# Finding the closest function describing a "magnetic line" (given magnetic readings)

Tags: approximation, interpolation, linear-approximation

I'm collecting data from a smartphone magnetometer while I move a magnet along a straight line (a slider). I am collecting the values of the magnetic field strength along the three axes.

I would like to find a function that could describe the movement of the magnet from the start point to the end point of the slider. I would like to do this using only the start and the end points values. I divided the slider in seven equidistant points and then recorded the value of the magnetic field in each position.

```
   x,         y,           z       position
-39.55,     -51.19,      -32.67     0
-26.01,     -41.83,      -32.95     0.17
-19.94,     -34.08,      -33.28     0.34
-16.43,     -26.62,      -32.72     0.51
-15.98,     -22.6,       -33.07     0.68
-15.93,     -20.72,      -32.96     0.85
-16.85,     -18.87,      -33.11     1
```

If I consider only the x column and the position column, the function should behave as closest as the following:

f(-39.55) = 0     f(-26.01) = 0.17     f(-19.94) = 0.34   f(-16.43) = 0.51
f(-15.98) = 0.68  f(-15.93) = 0.85     f(-16.85) = 1

My first thought was to use a line, so f(h) = |h - start| / |end - start| but the results were far from the behaviour I want

f(-39.55) = 0     f(-26.01) = 0.6      f(-19.94) = 0.86   f(-16.43) = 1.01
f(-15.98) = 1.03  f(-15.93) = 1.04     f(-16.85) = 1

I want to find a better function but I do not know what other type of functions to use. The chosen function should at least have the values as follow:
 f(start)=0 f(middle)=0.51 f(end)=1

The real problem is that I can't read the values in all the points every time the slider is being used (if the smartphone is moved all the values will change and the calibration phase will require to re-read the start and the end points). My idea was to find a good function and use all the stored values (the ones in between the start and the end) to check if the chosen function is correct.

What other type of function could I use to have this behaviour? Is there a better technique? Should I really get more middle-values in order to have a “decent” approximation?

Another idea I had was to use interpolation but I think I need at least the value in the middle point other than the start and end ones to have something meaningful. What kind of interpolation would be best? The problem in this case is that interpolation should use only the values of the point at the beginning and at the end (and if necessary the one in the middle).

Comment: I'm not confident I fully understand the question. If you only have the start and end points, then the best "fit" is a line. If you have intermediate points, then I would use a polynomial to interpolate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation. I'm no expert in this field though.

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully is clearer now. I think your answer is still meaningful but I hoped to find different functions (the best fit for two points only is not the best fit in my case)

Comment: "I would like to find a function that could describe the movement of the magnet from the start point to the end point of the slider". Is this a function  of time? My understanding is you want a function which, given a time value, will give you a position along the slider?

Comment: It's not a function of time. Given the values read by the magnetometer when the magnet is in a physical position on the slider I would like a value representing that position, For example when I read along the x axis the value -39.55 I would like the value 0 (meaning I'm at the beginning of the slider).

Comment: Ah OK. So it's a function from a $3$ dimensional magnetic reading to a $1$ dimensional point along the line. In that case, wouldn't the orientation of the line (slider) relative to the magnetic field be important?

Comment: I'm no physicist, but I think you'd need to consider the shape of the magnetic field in space? Maybe this is a question to ask the physics people?

Comment: I tried but the question was closed, an user told to try on the math stackexchange. The function is indeed from a 3 dimensional magnetic reading (as well as 2 or 1 if a "good" function can be found) to 1  point along the line. The slider has to be put always on the same side and in the same orientation (i.e. on the left of the phone with the start point parallel to the phone's speaker) so I think the orientation does not matter in this case.

Comment: Hmmm that's annoying, because this is really an applied maths / physics question. Anyway, would it be possible for you to provide a sketch of this apparatus including the magnetic field and the slider? This should make things clearer.

Comment: Look up pictures for the magnetic field- it doesn't seem to be a straight line, so I wouldn't expect the function mapping readings to a slider position to be linear either. Pics: https://www.google.ie/search?q=magnetic+field&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI4LTJ3q-axwIVMCDbCh240QTR&biw=1280&bih=663

Comment: Notice that from the magnetometer I get the "overall" readings, meaning that my magnet is not the only thing sensed. So the numbers I get are quite strange and the pictures of the magnetic field lines are quite distant from the pictures on google (so even less linear!). Anyway this is the configuration I have https://goo.gl/photos/i3TZ62pwt4qwjmtF8 (I made a mistake in a previous comment)
                             
Red: the magnetometer on the phone.            
Green: the slider.              
Yellow: the magnet.            
Black: magnetic field lines of the magnet.

Comment: Hmmm. Again I must stress that I am not very knowledgable in physics. Still, it looks like the field lines might be elliptical? Also, it looks like the horizontal distance from the slider to the phone will play a part in the calculation. What I think you need to do is work out what the $x$, $y$ and $z$ components of the magnetic field are, at the magnetometer (treat it as a point), when the slider is some arbitrary distance $l$ along the slider. You'd presumably need some 3D vector field equation for the magnetic field for this.

Comment: Then you should be able to work out, in reverse, $l$ in terms of the readings. You'll probably get some redundancy- which you can use to handle errors in the readings. That is, in an ideal theoretical world, you might be able to figure out $l$ from just, say 2 readings e.g. the $x$ and $y$ readings. Or perhaps even just one reading. But in reality you'd expect some error, so the other reading(s) should allow you to reduce this.

Comment: So to put that all together... It seems like what you need to do is: **a)** figure out the theoretical physics of 3D magnetic vector fields first (maybe look at physics threads) **b)** Come up with an algebraic expression relating your slider distance $l$ to the magnetometer readings **c)** plug in your data to the equation, and possibly use some interpolation method to reduce error. I would focus first on figuring out the theory first, then maybe re-post your problem here as an interpolation problem if you get there?

Comment: One more comment: your "overall" readings probably take in background noise- this is where the redundancy should help you. Taking more readings than you need should compensate for this noise.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, I'll try again to post a modified version of this question in the physics stackexchange to understand the theory behind this problem and then come back here with more information!

Comment: Great. Tag me if you do- I'm interested to see how it pans out.

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/199434/2451

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understood, you are looking for a model $$P=f(x,y,z)$$ to be adjusted on the basis of $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i,z_i,P_i)$. To me the problem is that $n$ is quite small.

As a simple attempt, I ignored the possible contribution of $z$ and tried $$P=a+bx+cy+dxy$$ which is just bilinear with respect to $x$ and $y$. Based on the data given in the post $$P=-0.120818-0.133217 x+0.0282536 y-0.00182842 x y$$ which is not too bad. The errors on $P$ values are $$\{0.0002,-0.0030,0.0099,-0.0061,-0.0291,0.0376,-0.0094\}$$ May be, this could give you some ideas.

Comment: Your function does work very well but my guess (since I did not quite understand how you managed to compute it) is that you used all the seven points available. Using all of them makes the functions almost perfect but my problem is that I cannot use all of them, I just need to find a function that behave like the one you gave me but uses only the first and the last point (and the middle one if necessary). From the comments to my question I guess that in order to do that I have to use information about the magnetic field as well.

Comment: I used a multilinear regression. I agree with your last sentence. Cheers :-)